# Add Data to Child List from Parent List form in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have 2 custom lists. **Purchase Order** (PO) and **Purchase Order Items** (POI). The POI list has a column PO ID, which is a lookup field to a column PO ID in the PO list. For every row in PO, there can be multiple rows in POI (one to many relationship).

When user tries to enter new items in the PO form, he needs to fill in the purchase items too, which will be stored in the POI list. The issue I am facing is, how do I allow the user to enter the data in both the lists at the same time, OOTB?

I have to do this using the list forms itself. Infopath is not an option available. SPD techniques are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done OOTB or with SharePoint Designer. Out of the box, SharePoint only allows you to enter one new item to one list at a time.

Using Edit In Datasheet is as close as you can some to editing or entering multiple list items at once. But even in this case, it is limited to a single list.

I have done a project similar to what you described using custom programming. I created custom forms along with custom field types that required custom javascript on the client and event receivers on the server. It was an interesting project, but it required a lot of moving parts.

Comment: I used a similar approach. Used a custom list form, added some jQuery, used the spservices jquery library to update the POI rows first, and then save the list form. Interesting way of doing it, i agree :)